# Divs always height of parent on load and resize jQuery or CSS

Tags: jquery, css, resize

I have 2 columns called .lcol and .rcol inside a parent called 'main-row' and I want to ensure that these are both always 100% height of the parent 'main-row'. This is because an element is floating absolute between the columns and I want to ensure they is no overlap of the element which is 236px high.

So far I have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(".rcol, .lcol").height($(".main-row").height() + 236);   
});
```

That's fine but it sets the children to a specific height and on resize it is under fined from the initial point.

I would also only like this to trigger if the class 'base' is present and also only when the window width is more than 480 px wide.

As you can see I'm using jQuery, but also if there is a pure CSS way to do it that would be very interesting.

Thanks very much

Glennyboy

**Update:**

This almost worked

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
//Initial load of page
jQuery(document).ready(sizeContent);

//Every resize of window
jQuery(window).resize(sizeContent);

//Dynamically assign height
function sizeContent() {
  var newHeight = jQuery(".main-row").height() + "px";
  jQuery(".rcol").css("height", newHeight);
 }
  </script>
```

The problem is that on every resize the .lcol gets incrementally bigger and outsized in proportion to the content.

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle?

Comment: Or at least post .main-row CSS

Comment: Perhaps start from here: http://jsfiddle.net/U59dT/